# CGAL - building INSTALL .sln faild

Tags: visual-studio, qt, boost, cgal

I have a problem while compiling CGAL I followed the steps here : http://www.cse.msu.edu/~ytong/CGAL_installation.ppt
I'm using VS2013 , cgal 4.9.1 , BOOST 1.59.0 ,Qt5.7.1

but when I reach at building INSTALL .sln step it show the following error:

```
Error   1   error MSB3073: The command "setlocal
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -DBUILD_TYPE=Debug -P cmake_install.cmake
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
:cmEnd
endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone
:cmErrorLevel
exit /b %1
:cmDone
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd
:VCEnd" exited with code 1. C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets  132 5   INSTALL
```

**output message :**

```
 file INSTALL cannot find
1>    "C:/dev/CGAL-4.9.1/build/bin/Debug/CGAL-vc120-mt-gd-4.9.1.dll".
1>  Call Stack (most recent call first):
1>    src/cmake_install.cmake:32 (include)
1>    cmake_install.cmake:91 (include)
```

any help please?

Answer (score 1):

Please use CGAL 4.12 and use installation instructions given on www.cgal.org

Comment: is it compatible with VS 2013?